# image fade in on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to recreate something like the effect that is happening on the left, with the logo fade in on the scroll of the page. Seen here http://www.vogue.co.uk/ when you scroll up.
 I have this, but it's really incorrect i think... SORRY GUYS, EDITED TO ADD HTML AND CSS

```
var divs = $('.logo-tiny');
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() <10 ){
         divs.stop(true,true).fadeOut("fast");
   } else {
         divs.stop(true,true).fadeIn("fast");
  }
  });​




<div id="header">
 <div id="logo"></div><div class="header-tiny"><div class="logo-tiny"></div>
  <div class="header-navi"><a class="header-link">link1</a> |<a     class="header-    link"> link2</a> |<a class="header-link"> link10</a></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    min-height:50px;
    margin:0 0 0 40px ;
    z-index: 1000;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}
#logo {
    background:url(RUNWAYMAGAZINE_LOGO-BK-hdr.png) no-repeat center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
    margin:10px;

}
.header-tiny {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 25px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
      }
.logo-tiny {
    background-color: #000;
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
       }
```

Comment: You should include some of your HTML as well.  This way people will be able to determine if this code correctly links with the HTML.

Comment: I think you're code is already working, just remove stop and check if your logo is already displayed or not before triggering the methods FadeIn and FadeOut

Comment: Actually, this is working. I updated your jsFiddle with minor changes http://jsfiddle.net/yB9Jq/6/

Comment: I'm not sure why mine is not working then... http://keithfrenchdesigns.com/RunwayMag/index.html

Comment: actually, your site is returning an error (using the <a href="https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console">console</a>). It tells basically that #left-navi doesn't exist. Since you bind the scroll event asking for the offset of this div (it creates an error and suspend the execution of this function).

Comment: Hmmm...ok, as i'm new to this, what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**css**

no scroll

```
visibility:hidden;
```

and top

```
visibility:visible;
```

animate

```
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
var divs = $('.logo-tiny');
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() <10 ){
       divs.fadeOut("fast");
       console.log('a');
   } else {
        divs.fadeIn("fast");
       console.log('b');
  }
});
```

working demo: [http://fiddle.jshell.net/D5M9H/]

Comment: I don't think you'are really improving the code we can see in the question since his code is already working. And formatting the code is a minimum...